# Collapsing multiple indices into groups based on overlapping targets

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently looking at the correlation between features in my dataset and need to group features that have similar targets into larger supergroups that can be used for a more general correlation analysis.

The features are one hot encoded and are in a pandas data-frame that looks similar to this:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
B 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
C 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
D 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

I would like the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
               1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
group1(A)      0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
group2(B,D,E,C)1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

I've already tried all forms of groupby and some of the methods in networkx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hidden network problem , so we using `networkx` after `merge`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index')
s=s.loc[s.value==1]
s=s.merge(s,on = 'variable')

import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(s, 'index_x', 'index_y')


l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
from collections import ChainMap

L=dict(ChainMap(*[dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(l)]))


df.groupby(L).sum().ge(1).astype(int)
Out[133]: 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
```

---

```
L
Out[134]: {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0}
```

Comment: related question, how could I group the features again, but this time in a combinatory manner where each group is constructed from the number of distinct groups that could be formed from the dataframe?

Comment: @petrepage you mean groupby the index again ? But  the index number from 0 to n is unique this time

Comment: Nice @WeNYoBen identifying the type of problem this.  +1